# How to find the limit of a integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification

I have to find the limit of the following integral:

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ be a function defined by the following:

$$\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=F(x)\text{ and }f(x)=e^{x^2}$$

Prove that $F(x)\rightarrow\infty$ where $x\rightarrow\infty$

I dont know if I have done it right, but this is what i have reached:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^xf(t)\ dt=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)=F(\infty)=\infty$$

I hope i can get some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your statement is not correct. Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Perhaps you have some more information about $f$ from earlier in the question? (My example was going to be $f(x) = e^{-x}$ :)

Comment: oh okay, i see that. $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}=0$

Comment: yes i do, $f(x)=e^{x^2}$

Comment: @TarekBadr That's not why. An integral can still diverge with the integrand converging to zero. It's because $\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+y^2}dy=\arctan(x)\to \pi/2$.

Comment: okay, do i have to say $\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt=x \cdot e^{x^2}$ and then find the limit of that?

Comment: @TarekBadr The fact that $f(x) = e^{x^2}$ is pretty vital to your question : ). Can you edit it into the body of your question using the "edit" button?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I have changed it now, my bad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, for each $x\in[0,\infty)$, $f(x)\geqslant1$,$$F(x)\geqslant\int_0^x1\,\mathrm dx=x$$and therefore $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

Take $g(t)=e^t$, and then apply comparison test.

$f(t)>g(t)$ as t getting large

You can refer to improper integral section in your calculus textbook.